# Extension of a bounded linear functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$ be an operator system. Suppose $T_n$ is a collection of all $n$-by-$n$ matrices equipped with the trace class norm. Let $\varphi:\mathcal{A}\widehat{\otimes} T_n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a linear functional with $\Vert\varphi\Vert=1$. Then it was concluded that, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists an extension $\hat{\varphi}:\mathcal{B{\mathcal{(H)}}}\widehat{\otimes} T_n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ of $\varphi$ such that $\Vert\hat{\varphi}\Vert=1$. My question is how does this conclusion follow?

This doubt comes while reading Theorem 4 of the paper [Extension of positive maps](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.05148.pdf) (see page 3, line 9).

It is to be noted that the conclusion would follow easily, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, if the inclusion $\mathcal{A}\widehat{\otimes} T_n\rightarrow\mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}\widehat{\otimes} T_n$ is isometric, that is, if the projective norm on $\mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}\widehat{\otimes} T_n$ is an extension of the projective norm of $\mathcal{A}\widehat{\otimes} T_n$. But, in general, the inclusion $\mathcal{A}\widehat{\otimes} T_n\rightarrow \mathcal{B\mathcal{(H)}}\widehat{\otimes} T_n$ is norm decreasing. The book "A theory of cross space" by Schatten contains an example (Corollary 3.5, page 57) that the above inclusion is not isometric in general.

However, I think the author means the inclusion $\mathcal{A}\widehat{\otimes} T_n\rightarrow\mathcal{B}\mathcal{(H)}\widehat{\otimes} T_n$ is isometric in this special situation, that is, when $\mathcal{A}$ is an operator system
and $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional. If so, it will lead to the conclusion written in the first paragraph immediately using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

I tried to prove this in various ways but could not able to prove it.

Any comment is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  The linked paper makes no such claim, and is very careful to point out that you need extra hypotheses to extend functionals.

Comment: @MatthewDaws I have edited the question. Please read it now.

Comment: You have now edited away the reference to *where* "it was concluded that" there exists an extension.

Comment: @SamHopkins it was removed since it does not contain the example of what I mentioned. But the reference to that example was given there. Anyway here is that article https://msp.org/pjm/1967/22-1/pjm-v22-n1-p09-p.pdf.

Comment: @Piku: The point is, it is unclear right now if you are saying "I read this specific fact asserted somewhere and I want to know why it's true" or if you are saying "I am wondering if the following might be true."

Comment: @SamHopkins I read this somewhere without explanation. I want to know why it's true as I am not able to see it with an effort of so many weeks.

Comment: @Piku: in that case, it would be really helpful for everyone trying to answer your question if you cited specifically where you read it.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ok, I will add the reference. Anyway, that paper has some other objective which has nothing to do with this basis doubt.  I believe that the author left it for the reader to fill this basis up but, unfortunately, I am not able to do it on my own.

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretation of what the paper you link to says is confused.

- The paper considers only *positive* maps $\phi:A\rightarrow M_n$;
- The paper does not consider $A \widehat\otimes M_n$ but rather $A \widehat\otimes T_n$ where $T_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrices with the *trace class norm*.

The paper (or really an "addenda") is hard to read, because you need access to Stormer's book, reference [6].  However, this all said, *I agree with you that the argument seems wrong*.  The only thing [6, Lemma 4.2.2] shows is that the dual of $A \widehat\otimes T_n$ is the bounded linear maps $A\rightarrow M_n$.  Of course, this says nothing about the inclusion

$$ A \widehat\otimes T_n \rightarrow B(H) \widehat\otimes T_n $$

and it does seem to simply be asserted without proof (in the paper you link) that this inclusion is an isometry, not merely norm-decreasing.

I'm afraid I don't have more to say right now; but I think your doubts are reasonable.